# Shiny server is returning wrong value for function

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am new to shiny (and any web app stuff), but fairly well versed in R. I am trying to build a fairly basic page, which runs an API call before loading the page, takes some input based on the response, and then runs another API call and does some analysis. I am having trouble with the inputs.

Here is my UI:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("IGP Risk Analysis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("portfolio", "Underlying Portfolio:", 
                  choices = portfolioList),  
      selectInput("portDate", "Portfolio Date:",
                  choices = "Pick a portfolio..."),
      width = 2),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")), 
                  tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")), 
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

My server code is below:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    portfolioInput <- reactive({
      temp <- setnames(sendRequest(theURL, myUN, myPW, action = "GetPortfolios"), "Available Portfolios")
      portfolioList <- temp[!grepl("AAA|ZZZ",unlist(temp)),]
      return(portfolioList)
    })

  observe({
    portfolioDates <- setnames(sendRequest(theURL, myUN, myPW, action = "GetPortfolioDates", 
                                           portfolioName = input$portfolio, portfolioCurrency = "USD"),
                               "Available Dates")
    updateSelectInput(session, "portDate",
                    choices = c("Pick One", portfolioDates),
                    selected = "Pick One")
  })
})
```

It is working, without errors or warnings, but the first input box is displaying the results of sendRequest(). It is not setting the names, or subsetting the response. I.e. - in the first selectInput box I am getting:

```
theResponse.ArrayOfString.string
AAA - IGP\\Diver\\20151007
AAA - IGP\\Diver\\TEST
REAL
BD
Bvdh
Cap
Cas
Diver
IGP Aggregate
ZZZ - Archive
ZZZ - Archive\\AAA - IGP
```

Where I want:

```
Available Portfolios
REAL
BD
Bvdh
Cap
Cas
Diver
IGP Aggregate
```

This makes no sense to me, as it seems to be ignoring code.

Since the portfolioList is static, in that is only needs to be loaded once when you first load the page, I tried getting the list outside of the server function. I was thinking this would set a global variable I could then reference in the UI. This did not work. Any thoughts why that approach wouldnt work?

Does this have anything to do with the 'session' in the server function? Do I have old sessions running or something? Is 'session' the R session? Does it restart when I restart the app in RStudio?

Comment: You need to return your portfolioList object in your reactive function. Furthermore I would recommend to use renderUI for dynamic ui parts.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have tried that, and it does not change anything. Also, I tried using renderUI, and I could not get it to work.

Comment: Is this the exact code your running? Thought this is a sketch, your shiny environment should not know portfolioList at all, try calling portfolioInput() inside ui.r - but I'm not sure this will work in your ui.r. I'm trying to fetch something together..

Comment: Ha! That's exactly my point! I don't know where it is coming from... That's why I thought it was an old session running in the background or something. This is the exact code I am running.

Comment: I just restarted RStudio, and now it does not work. I am getting: object 'portfolioList' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you something to start with, minimal example of renderUI:

```
    shinyApp(

  ui = sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("portfolio"),  
      selectInput("portDate", "Portfolio Date:",
                  choices = "Pick a portfolio..."),
      width = 2),
    mainPanel()),


  server = function(input, output) {

    ui1 <- reactive({

      temp <- c("AAA","1","2","3","ZZZ")
      temp[!grepl("AAA|ZZZ",temp)]

    })

    output$portfolio <- renderUI ({

      selectInput("portfolio", "Underlying Portfolio:", 
                  choices = ui1())

    })

  }
)
```

To add on my comments, you can't simply call functions or objects in ui.r, you render your objects in server.r and call those objects, marked as output$name in ui.r. 
I would advise you to do the shiny tutorials http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/.

Comment: This is the problem I was running into earlier when I tried to use renderUI. Running your code, I keep getting ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer. (I am using chrome as a browser, so it should work.) Sorry, I was actually running your code, with my observe() function in the server.

Comment: Hm that's strange, does it work if you copy this code into your r console?

Comment: How do i get the selection of the output$portfolio selectInput back out to the portDate selectInput?

Comment: Edited a reactive function which you can use in other requests. I guess you want to use the input of "portfolio" for "portDate"? Just call input$portfolio and construct another renderUI in server.r - or you have the option to use your updateSelectInput, but just rendering a new ui might be easier to start with.

Comment: I need to use the selection of portfolio for a new API call which then returns the dates available for that portfolio. So, i need the selection from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody!!! I figured it out, or I figured out a solution to the problem. Much thanks to Sebastion for steering me in the right direction. (Also thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839372/shiny-selectinput-subset-based-on-input).) I only posted an answer to kind of put a bow on this. All props to Sebastion and others.

Here is the working ui:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("IGP Risk Analysis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("portfolio"),  
      uiOutput("portDate"),
      width = 2),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")), 
                  tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")), 
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

Here is the server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$portfolio <- renderUI ({
    temp <- setNames(sendRequest(theURL, myUN, myPW, action = "GetPortfolios"), "Available Portfolios")
    temp <- temp[sapply(temp, function (x) !grepl("AAA|ZZZ",x)),]
    selectInput("portfolio", "Underlying Portfolio:", choices = c("Pick One",temp))
  })

  output$portDate <- renderUI ({
    if (is.null(input$portfolio) || input$portfolio == "Pick One") return() else { 
           portfolioDates <- setNames(sendRequest(theURL, myUN, myPW, action = "GetPortfolioDates", 
                                                  portfolioName = input$portfolio, portfolioCurrency = "USD"),
                                      "Available Dates")
           selectInput("portDate", "Portfolio Date",
                             choices = c("Pick One", portfolioDates),
                             selected = "Pick One")
    }

  })
})
```