# Plot different reactive graph using different dataset and columns based on reacitve inputs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently trying to teach myself shiny, and am having a little trouble.
I want to make an app that has a menu for which dataset the user would like to plot from, followed by another menu for which variable they would like to plot (against the date column)

I have managed to get the reactive menus working, but i am struggling to work out how to 'call' the selected dataset. I have read a lot of posts (e.g  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839372/shiny-selectinput-subset-based-on-input),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635673/select-a-variable-from-drop-down-and-pass-it-as-an-argument-in-reactiveplot-in-r)) but none seem to deal with the multiple dataset problem.

My code currently looks like this, with my issues being on the last few lines (how do I get to the mydata within outVar()?!?).

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

datafiles<-c("Data/try2.txt","Data/Poland.txt","Data/Romania.txt","Data/Hungary.txt","Data/KHR.txt")


runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', datafiles),
    selectInput('columns', 'Columns', ""),
    plotOutput('graph')
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session){
    outVar = reactive({
      mydata = read.table(paste0(input$dataset), sep = '\t', header=TRUE)
      names(mydata)

    })
    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "columns",
                        choices = outVar()
      )})
    output$graph<-renderPlot({data<- outVar$mydata
    plot(data$Date,data$paste0(input$columns))})
  }
))

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: are you getting an error message in your app? if so, what is it saying? 
have you tried data <- outVar()$mydata in the output$graph ?

Comment: just tried adding the outVar()$mydata, still getting the same error (Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors).

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work with the data I used. I kept getting a different error however. I took out the observe event in the answer below. You should be able to do what you want without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have your data, but, I used the wine quality data to build this. 
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality

Hope this helps

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)


datafile1 <- read_delim(file = "Data/winequality-red.csv", delim = ";")
datafile2 <- read_delim(file = "Data/winequality-white.csv", delim = ";")
# datafiles<-c("Data/try2.txt","Data/Poland.txt","Data/Romania.txt","Data/Hungary.txt","Data/KHR.txt")

datafiles <- list(datafile1, datafile2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', choices = c("Red" = "1", "White" = "2")),
  selectInput('column', 'Choose column', choices = c("2" = "2", "3" = "3")),
  plotOutput('graph')
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  outVar <- reactive({
    temp <- datafiles[[as.numeric(input$dataset)]]
    temp <- temp[,c(1, as.numeric(input$column))]
  })

  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    plot(outVar())
  })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! In the first temp<- as.data.frame() line, is the as.numeric necessary? the first column is a column of dates and so i'm getting the error 'need finite xlim values'.

If i remove the as.numeric then i get 'undefined columns selected'.

Comment: as.numeric would be necessary because when you're selecting from the input your choices are being defined as a character rather than a numeric. you want to change to a numeric so that you can use that to select your column. 

the first temp line is only selecting the dataset from the list of datasets. the second temp line has a 1, and the selected column (I assumed that column one was your date column). So it's going in steps, first taking the right data, making it a dataframe, then taking the 1st column and the column you select from your drop down list.

Comment: I guess the question is how is your data structured? based on your question, I assumed that each dataset had several columns, with column 1 being the date column and columns 2, ..., n being some value that you want to plot against the date?  I realized that you don't need to include the as.data.frame above, so I've taken that out.

Comment: Hi, sorry i wrote a reply but forgot to send... It's been a long day. You correctly assumed the date is always the first column. It's just that when i run the code it gives the error NAs introduced by coercion ... need finite xlim values. When i run it with two numeric columns plotted against each other it works perfectly!

Comment: I think that'll be more an issue with the plot than the app itself. if you include:   `output$table <- renderTable({
    outVar()
  })`

in your server and   `tableOutput('table')`
in your UI below the `plotOutput` you should see how the data is structured. Then it will be a matter of updating the plot function or using ggplot to do what you want.

I don't have access to time series data so I can't be of much more help but I think you're 95% of the way there. If this solves your question make sure to mark and upvote if helpful

Comment: this may be helpful: https://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-time-series-data-using-ggplot2/

Comment: oh, one other thing, if you do decide to use ggplot, make sure you include a `print()` statement within the `output$graph`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I actually started off using ggplot but switched it to just plot to make the code neater for this question.