# R - Invalid xlim value in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make an app that has a menu for which dataset the user would like to plot from, followed by another menu for which variable they would like to plot (against the date column). However I get Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value.
My code currently looks like this, with my issues being on the last few lines (probably with outVar). 
If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

datafile1<- read_excel("C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/so.xlsx")
datafile2<- read_excel("C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/gk.xlsx")


datafiles <- list(datafile1, datafile2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Choose Dataset', choices = c("goalkeeper" = "1", "defender" = "2")),
  selectInput('column', 'Choose column', choices = c("8" = "8", "9" = "9")),
  plotOutput('graph')
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  outVar <- reactive({
    temp <- datafiles[[as.numeric(input$dataset)]]
    temp <- temp[,c(1, as.numeric(input$column))]
  })

  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    plot(outVar())
  })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server) 



My structure dates:
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   500 obs. of  73 variables:
 $ Player                 : chr  "L. Bonucci" "Piqué" "Sergio Ramos" "M. Hummels" ...
 $ Team                   : chr  "Milan" "Barcelona" "Real Madrid" "Bayern München" ...
 $ Position               : chr  "RCB, CB, LCB" "RCB" "LCB" "LCB" ...
 $ Age                    : num  30 30 31 28 25 31 29 24 23 23 ...
 $ Market value           : num  4.0e+07 4.0e+07 4.0e+07 4.0e+07 3.8e+07 3.8e+07 3.8e+07 3.5e+07 3.5e+07 3.5e+07 ...
 $ Matches played         : num  49 43 46 46 52 55 23 41 51 46 ...
 $ Minutes played         : num  4307 3892 4294 3773 4402 ...
 $ Goals total            : num  5 3 9 2 5 3 0 4 4 2 ...
 $ Assists                : num  1 0 2 2 7 2 1 2 0 0 ...
```

Comment: Your reactive conductor `outVar` returns nothing.

Comment: But I return only plot.

Comment: This code does something like `plot(NULL)` because `outVar()` returns nothing.

Comment: So, What should I change?

Comment: Maybe remove the second "`temp <-`" in `outVar`. In this way `outVar` will return `temp[,c(1, as.numeric(input$column))]`.

Comment: Still does not work. I modeled on this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874569/plot-different-reactive-graph-using-different-dataset-and-columns-based-on-reaci